# Loop condition debugging for Codetown city bus problem

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I have the problem below to code in python. I have completed the code and I can get the correct answers according to examples provided but the program is not asking the question for the the last stop where all the passengers must get off. It always finishes on the 2nd last stop but still gives the correct answer. I know it has something to do with the loop condition but I just can't see it.

I am also having trouble putting in the code for putting in invalid answers. Can anyone please offer any assistance.

Problem
The mayor of Codetown thinks that current school times are not aligned to the needs of modern working parents. However, she realises that modifying school hours will have flow-on effects to areas such as public transport. Therefore, before making any changes, she has decided she needs more data to determine how public transport is currently utilised. She has asked you to develop a program that can be used by the town's bus drivers to collect some of this information.

A Codetown city bus can hold 35 passengers. For each route, a bus starts at a particular bus stop and picks up any passengers that are waiting (provided they all fit on the bus - no more passengers are picked up if the bus is full). Until the end of the route, the bus repeatedly moves to the next bus stop, dropping off any passengers that wish to get off the bus at that point and picking up any waiting passengers that can fit on the bus.

The mayor has asked you to develop a Python program that does the following. At the start of the program, the driver should be asked the route number, how many stops there are along that route, and the number of passengers at the start of the route. Then, for each remaining stop, the driver should be prompted to enter the number of passengers leaving the bus, and the number of passengers waiting to get on the bus at that stop (though all passengers must leave and no passengers can get on the bus at the last stop at the end of the route). Your program should then output the route number, the total number of passengers that got on the bus ("happy customers"), the total number of passengers that were unable to get on the bus because it was too full ("unhappy customers"), and the ratio of happy customers to unhappy customers (to two decimal places, and set to 0 if there were no unhappy customers).

Here is my code below. I have tried to had +1 to the for loop after num_stops and it gives me the last stop but it wants to ask how many passengers are waiting to get on the last stop when everyone has to get off. The last question should be 'How many passengers left the bus at stop 5 for instance if there are 5 stops on the route.

```
def collect_data():
    route_number = int(input("Please enter the route number: "))
    num_stops = int(input("Please enter the number of stops on this route: "))
    passengers_at_start = int(input("How many passengers were waiting for the bus at stop 1: "))
    return route_number, num_stops, passengers_at_start

def calculate_customers(num_stops, passengers_at_start):
    happy_customers = passengers_at_start
    unhappy_customers = 0

    for stop in range(2, num_stops):
        passengers_leaving = int(input(f"How many passengers left at stop {stop}: "))
        passengers_waiting = int(input(f"How many passengers were waiting for the bus at stop {stop}: "))

        passengers_at_start = passengers_at_start - passengers_leaving
        available_space = 35 - passengers_at_start

        if passengers_waiting > available_space:
            happy_customers += available_space
            unhappy_customers += passengers_waiting - available_space
            passengers_at_start = 35
        else:
            happy_customers += passengers_waiting
            passengers_at_start += passengers_waiting

    return happy_customers, unhappy_customers

def main():
    route_number, num_stops, passengers_at_start = collect_data()
    happy_customers, unhappy_customers = calculate_customers(num_stops, passengers_at_start)

    print(f"Route number: {route_number}")
    print(f"Happy customers: {happy_customers}")
    print(f"Unhappy customers: {unhappy_customers}")
    print(f"Ratio of happy customers to unhappy customers: {happy_customers/unhappy_customers:.2f}" if unhappy_customers > 0 else "Ratio of happy customers to unhappy customers: 0.00")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're correct in that the range for the for loop should be `range(2, num_stops + 1)` since it will iterate from `2` to `num_stops` and you want to start the calculation from second stop to last stop. To avoid the program asking for the input `How many passengers were waiting for the bus at stop {stop}:` , you can add an `if` condition to check if the current stop is not the last stop (ie `stop != num_stops`) before prompting the user input

```
def calculate_customers(num_stops, passengers_at_start):
    happy_customers = passengers_at_start
    unhappy_customers = 0

    for stop in range(1, num_stops + 1):
        passengers_leaving = int(input(f"How many passengers left at stop {stop}: "))
        if stop != num_stops:
            passengers_waiting = int(input(f"How many passengers were waiting for the bus at stop {stop}: "))
        else:
            passengers_waiting = 0

        passengers_at_start = passengers_at_start - passengers_leaving
        available_space = 35 - passengers_at_start

        if passengers_waiting > available_space:
            happy_customers += available_space
            unhappy_customers += passengers_waiting - available_space
            passengers_at_start = 35
        else:
            happy_customers += passengers_waiting
            passengers_at_start += passengers_waiting

    return happy_customers, unhappy_customers
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! Do know where  I put in the loop condition for if they put in a wrong answer or a negative integer.

Comment: You could enclose a while loop inside every `input(...)` with the condition to only break the loop if the input is valid (ie `while passengers_leaving >= 0 and passengers_leaving <= happy_customers`)